# Why does the text of my div appear faded when I turn the div into a link?

Tags: html, css

I have a section with a summary on it that I'm using as a large button to take the user to an article. As soon as I surround the section with link tags though, the h5 and p children appear to have faded. The h2 one does not. When the div is hovered over, however, the text comes back to its normal full opacity.

```
<a href="Articles/Slide1.html">
<section id="slide-1" class="homeSlide fullLengthSlide">
    <div class="hsContainer">
        <div class="summary">
            <h2>This appears fully opaque, i.e. normal.</h2>
            <h5>This appears faded</h5>
            <p>This also appears faded</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</a>
```

CSS

```
.homeSlide {
    display: table;
    background-color: #3399FF;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s;
    transition: background-color 0.5s;
}

.homeSlide:hover {
    background-color: #70B8FF;
}
```

I really just want the background color to change on hover and have the text fully opaque at all times. Any thoughts?

Comment: You mean that it has an opacity when you hover over it?

Comment: looks fine to me: http://jsfiddle.net/dby84gbo/  Other CSS on your page might be causing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its is bcoz now it will inherit css of anchor tag `<a>`

Try this:

```
a{
    color:black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some style gets inherited from somewhere. Try adding color to your text elements -

```
.homeSlide {
    display: table;
    background-color: #3399FF;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s;
    transition: background-color 0.5s;
}
h2,h5,p { color:black;}
.homeSlide:hover {
    background-color: #70B8FF;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0p19o0s5/